# Getting specific strings from a URL

Tags: php, url

I have the following URL in which i want to use splitting like preg_split or parse_url in order to get only the string after the equal and not the abc string.So i want to display content except DDDD& , AAAA& and GGGG.How can i do this?

```
http://localhost/?abc=DDDD&abc=AAAA&abc=GGGG
```

Comment: Why are you building url like this? Just make key `abc` array like `http://localhost/?abc[]=DDDD&abc[]=AAAA&abc[]=GGGG` and then you can just get abc values with `$_GET['abc']`.

Comment: you mean that i need just adding [] after abc?

Comment: If you wish to make abc array, yes.

Comment: i just want text after abc= every time and display it in seperate variables

Comment: @openc as Glavic said , if you want to do abc three time , and not other names , you will need array

Comment: @FaceOfJock how can i do this in array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to change url from this :

```
http://localhost/?abc=DDDD&abc=AAAA&abc=GGGG
```

**to this :**

```
http://localhost/?abc[]=DDDD&abc[]=AAAA&abc[]=GGGG
```

And access all values throw array `$_GET['abc']` like this :

```
<?php
  foreach($_GET['abc']  as $abc) echo $abc.'<br/>';
?>
```

Comment: that's interesting!i will try.I think this is the solution to my problem.

Comment: finally i tried it and it was correct and so simple!thanks FaceofJock.

Answer (score 0):

Those are called GET variables, and can be accessed by the global GET array.

```
echo $_GET['abc'];
```

Comment: This will return the last i.e: `GGGGGG`

Comment: i have not tried it though but i read also in other places that get variable is the key